# How do I select other objects in an array that has the same object in javascript and json?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm trying to create a code structure where people will list products based on the options they choose, but I got stuck at one point.

I'm pulling the data from the json file but I'm trying to provide the condition as follows. I want to extract the titles, prices and other information from the arrays with the same etiket values and print them to the document.

my Json data:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Zincir Tasarımlı El Çantası",
    "price": "49.90",
    "upPrice": "69.90",
    "currency": "&#8378;",
    "images": "./images/yeni.jpg",
    "etiket": {
        "cinsiyet": "kadin",
        "yas": "yas16-20",
        "konsept": "yilbasi"
    }
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Tüylü Kısa Kol Çanta",
    "price": "74.50",
    "upPrice": "99.90",
    "currency": "&#8378;",
    "images": "./images/yeni1.jpg",
    "etiket": {
        "cinsiyet": "kadin",
        "yas": "yas20-30",
        "konsept": "yilbasi"
    }
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Zincir Detaylı Kemer Tokalı Çanta",
    "price": "89.90",
    "upPrice": "99.90",
    "currency": "&#8378;",
    "images": "./images/yeni3.jpg",
    "etiket": {
        "cinsiyet": "erkek",
        "yas": "yas16-20",
        "konsept": "yilbasi"
    }
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Zincirli Uzun Kol Deri Çanta",
    "price": "69.90",
    "upPrice": "89.90",
    "currency": "&#8378;",
    "images": "./images/yeni4.jpg",
    "etiket": {
        "cinsiyet": "erkek",
        "yas": "yas20-30",
        "konsept": "yilbasi"
    }
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Zincir Tasarımlı El Çantası",
    "price": "49.90",
    "upPrice": "69.90",
    "currency": "&#8378;",
    "images": "./images/yeni5.jpg",
    "etiket": {
        "cinsiyet": "erkek",
        "yas": "yas30-40",
        "konsept": "yilbasi"
    }
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "title": "Zincirli Deri Desenli Çanta",
    "price": "109.90",
    "upPrice": "129.90",
    "currency": "&#8378;",
    "images": "./images/yeni6.jpg",
    "etiket": {
        "cinsiyet": "erkek",
        "yas": "yas45ustu",
        "konsept": "yilbasi"
    }
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "title": "Kısa Kollu Deri Çanta",
    "price": "199.90",
    "upPrice": "269.90",
    "currency": "&#8378;",
    "images": "./images/yeni7.jpg",
    "etiket": {
        "cinsiyet": "kadin",
        "yas": "yas30-45",
        "konsept": "yilbasi"
    }
},
{
    "id": 8,
    "title": "Kahverengi Deri Desenli Kısa Kol Çanta",
    "price": "349.90",
    "upPrice": "369.90",
    "currency": "&#8378;",
    "images": "./images/yeni8.jpg",
    "etiket": {
        "cinsiyet": "kadin",
        "yas": "yas45ustu",
        "konsept": "yilbasi"
    }
}]
```

I'm giving an example. I want to draw the titles of the same *"yilbasi"* values, *"yas16-20"* values and *"kadin"* values to the page with innerHTML.

But I don't know how to pull the data of the ones with the same values. I have not been able to create its structure. I want to do it with pure javascript if possible.

Comment: You can use `filter` and `map` methods of `Array`. Filter by the properties of `etiket` matching the provided values of `cinsiyet`, `yas`, and `konsept`, and then use `map` to extract the attributes you need, such as `title` and `price`.

Comment: @tromgy I think that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks for guiding. I took a look at these concepts and it seems to give the result I want, if I find a solution, I will share the solution here, thanks again.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for the warning, I've edited it again.

Comment: Cheers! Thank you for fixing 

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** I found the solution very quickly with [@tromgy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9508635/tromgy)'s guidance. I will try to mention it below for those who have the same problem.

Js kodlarım:

```js
const productData = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Zincir Tasarımlı El Çantası",
        "price": "49.90",
        "upPrice": "69.90",
        "currency": "&#8378;",
        "images": "./images/yeni.jpg",
        "etiket": {
            "cinsiyet": "kadin",
            "yas": "yas16-20",
            "konsept": "yilbasi"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Tüylü Kısa Kol Çanta",
        "price": "74.50",
        "upPrice": "99.90",
        "currency": "&#8378;",
        "images": "./images/yeni1.jpg",
        "etiket": {
            "cinsiyet": "kadin",
            "yas": "yas16-20",
            "konsept": "yilbasi"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Zincir Detaylı Kemer Tokalı Çanta",
        "price": "89.90",
        "upPrice": "99.90",
        "currency": "&#8378;",
        "images": "./images/yeni3.jpg",
        "etiket": {
            "cinsiyet": "erkek",
            "yas": "yas16-20",
            "konsept": "yilbasi"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Zincirli Uzun Kol Deri Çanta",
        "price": "69.90",
        "upPrice": "89.90",
        "currency": "&#8378;",
        "images": "./images/yeni4.jpg",
        "etiket": {
            "cinsiyet": "erkek",
            "yas": "yas16-20",
            "konsept": "yilbasi"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "Zincir Tasarımlı El Çantası",
        "price": "49.90",
        "upPrice": "69.90",
        "currency": "&#8378;",
        "images": "./images/yeni5.jpg",
        "etiket": {
            "cinsiyet": "erkek",
            "yas": "yas45ustu",
            "konsept": "yilbasi"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "title": "Zincirli Deri Desenli Çanta",
        "price": "109.90",
        "upPrice": "129.90",
        "currency": "&#8378;",
        "images": "./images/yeni6.jpg",
        "etiket": {
            "cinsiyet": "erkek",
            "yas": "yas45ustu",
            "konsept": "yilbasi"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Kısa Kollu Deri Çanta",
        "price": "199.90",
        "upPrice": "269.90",
        "currency": "&#8378;",
        "images": "./images/yeni7.jpg",
        "etiket": {
            "cinsiyet": "kadin",
            "yas": "yas30-45",
            "konsept": "yilbasi"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "title": "Kahverengi Deri Desenli Kısa Kol Çanta",
        "price": "349.90",
        "upPrice": "369.90",
        "currency": "&#8378;",
        "images": "./images/yeni8.jpg",
        "etiket": {
            "cinsiyet": "kadin",
            "yas": "yas45ustu",
            "konsept": "yilbasi"
        }
    }
]
let demo = document.getElementById("demo");
const titles = productData.reduce((acc, prdct) =>
prdct.etiket.cinsiyet =="kadin"
&& prdct.etiket.yas =="yas16-20"
&& prdct.etiket.konsept=="yilbasi" ? acc + prdct.title + "</br>" : acc, "");

demo.innerHTML = titles;
```

```html
<div id=demo></div>
```

This is how it turned out, as I wanted it to be.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question, you would iterate the array, and for each object retrieve the values you care about.

Because you said 'pure javascript', I'm going to use traditional loops instead of array methods like `includes` and `find` and `forEach`, but you could do it with either.

The niave approach in the loop would be to loop again, checking for duplicates.

```js
for (let i = 0; i > array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (i === j) {
            // skip when we are going to compare an element with itself
            continue;
        }
    
        if (
            array[i].etiket.cinsiyet === array[j].etiket.cinsiyet
            && array[i].etiket.yas === array[j].etiket.yas
            && array[i].etiket.konsept === array[j].etiket.konsept
        ) {
            // you have found two array elements that share 'etiket' values, they are the elements at 'i' and 'j'. do whatever you want.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Those array methods *ARE* Javascript

Comment: I'm aware of that, that's why I put 'pure javascript' in quotes - pure in the sense of simple. Those array methods literally just implement the loops I wrote internally (usually, it's implementation dependent).

Comment: pure and simple are not synonymous.  And the Array.prototype methods are not only simple, but they are idiomatic these days.

Comment: That is a fair point, I probably shouldn't have said I will write traditional loops *because* the asker requested pure javascript. I agree it's idiomatic, but there are plenty of people out there who prefer traditional loops, and plenty of good reasons to prefer them. 

I don't think it's particularly a big deal. 

We're talking about the difference of writing a loop, or calling an existing function that internally performs that exact same loop, but with the overhead of a function call (yes I know V8 can sometimes inline these calls, whatever).

Comment: I would add that the Array.prototype methods, because again, they are executing a loop structure internally, they by definition are *less simple* than what I wrote. They are what I wrote + more stuff. Abstracting away complexity doesn't remove it, it just hides it.

Comment: Again, and I'm not going to argue the point any further, the Array.prototype methods *ARE* "pure" Javascript